Boy in bed with his girlfriend, then his angry father appears
I remember this scene from the film: 
A young boy and his girlfriend are lying in his bed and the boy is telling the girl about his past. He says that he took drugs. The girl says rising back from darkness/hell makes us stronger. They then proceed to make love, after which the girl gets up to go to bathroom. She finds the boy's drunk/angry father at the door. He starts verbally abusing her, calling her a whore/bitch(?). The boy then gets up and warns the father that if he threatens/abuses the girlfriend again, he'll beat/kill him(?).
The movie was in English was seen sometime from 1990 - 2010.

Sounds vaguely like some scenes in season 2 of Breaking Bad.

Definitely not that .. I saw this movie many years ago ..

Can you pinpoint a decade?

saw it before 2010 .. so the movie could have been between 1990s to 2010

OK, thanks. Added.

I've edited the question to try and make it clearer. Can you double check my wording. It was unclear if you meant the boy threatened the father or if the father threatened the boy. I would assume the latter, but your original wording suggested otherwise.

boy threatens the father after the father calls the girl names

@johnmason: Perfect, I've edited again to make that clear. I hope you find what you're looking for soon. And welcome to the site!

@johnmason Breaking Bad  is not a movie :)

My brain strongly suggests that you're looking for this one Feast of Love (2007).
In the middle of the movie, this teenage guy you're talking about, Oscar (Toby Hemingway) is with his girlfriend naked and the guy's father walks right into the room with out knocking while the girl is in search of bathroom. 
This is the conversation takes place between the couple regarding his drug issue.

-I had this dream one night while I was wasted. 
-There was this African monkey whispering all this creepy shit in my
  ear. 
-He said that if I didn't get clean I was gonna die young, 
-OD in an alleyway on a pile of garbage. 
-And that morning I woke up and I went to my first meeting. 
-It was seven months and two weeks ago. 
.....
.....
-Hey, where's the little girl's room? 
-Across the hall. 

Then the father enters the room.

-Oscar! Goddamn it! 
-You get that girl out of your room, Oscar! 
-Get the fuck away! 
-You do it right now, damn it! Do you hear me? 
.....
-Hello, missy. 
-Pleased to meet you. The name's Chloe. 
-Yeah, well, don't you come in this house again unless I invite you. 
-There'll be trouble I can't be responsible for. 
-You hear me? 

Now the boy threatens his father. 

-Hey, don't be scared, all right? 
-He is a mean son of a bitch, but I can be, too.

And I think in the latter part, the guy's father insinuates his son's girlfriend a thief and verbally abuses her a whore.
The conversation goes between them like this.

-You been selling my shit? 
-I'm not a thief. 
-Where's my pillow, then? Huh, bitch? 
-What pillow? 
-My wife give it to me in Atlantic City. 
-Look, I don't know what you're talking about. 
-I see right through you, whore. 
-I swear I never took anything from your house, except Oscar and he's not yours.


Seems like a match. His father barges in after Oscar talks to her about quitting drugs, if I'm not mistaken.
